# How can I force less to stop buffering its input line by line?

Tags: less

When reading from stdin, `less` does not display any output until a whole line has been read.

I use a script that prints progress on one line, without printing a newline, and I would really like to be able to see this progress even when I pipe it to `less`.

Here is some example bash code to demonstrate my problem:

```
while true ; do echo -n zzz ; sleep 1s ; done | less
```

Is there a button I can press to force `less` to display its collected input, or is there an option to disable this kind of buffering?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.

You could instead filter the input to insert line breaks. Here's a very simplistic filter which doesn't take care of where it puts the line breaks; it's definitely possible to improve on that, but at least you'll see your output in near-real time.

```
perl -e '$| = 1; while (sysread STDIN, $_, 80) {print; /\n/ or print "\n"}
```

Alternatively, you could switch to another viewer. Emacs's shell mode is a heavyweight solution if you don't otherwise use Emacs. You would run the script in a `*shell*` buffer (created with `M-x shell`). Apart from the different interface, it can do all that less can do, and more, including showing the output as it comes.