# How to pipe to less unbuffered?

Tags: pipe, buffer

I'm trying to display progress, and make it usable under `less`:

```
while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done | less
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from the `echo` in the `while` loop is always unbuffered. If you remove the `-n` option, you will see the lines containing the dots appearing each second.

It seems that `less` always tries to read a complete line and won't display it until it reaches end of line or end of file. There doesn't seem to be an option to change that.

Comment: Are you sure it has to do specifically with `less`, not with piping in general?

Comment: @x-yuri why don't you try it yourself: `while echo -n .; do sleep 1; done | cat | cat | cat | cat` ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'm really sure that a command in a shell pipe will write it's output before it terminates, because there can't be a user mode buffer after the program exits.  And the `echo` command, although a shell builtin, behaves the same as an external command.

Comment: Well, I rather meant that maybe it has something to do with `libc` buffering the communication. But judging from `strace` [output](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/575d4ebb40e990677ff856bf35d84386) it succeeds (doesn't block) in reading each coming "." character, but doesn't display them for one or another reason.

Comment: Oh, there's a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22508/how-can-i-force-less-to-stop-buffering-its-input-line-by-line).